# How to run test automation scripts written in pycharm from JIRA?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, jira, automation-testing

I have created test suite in pycharm using python-selenium-robot framework.
Now I want to run it from JIRA.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How would you use JIRA to run the script? Rather try exploring any CI/CD tool to run that and then update comment/issues on JIRA.. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Hi, I have test suite written using python-selenium-robot framework in pycharm. I need to run that suite from JIRA and get collected results in JIRA in tabulated, dashboard format with statistics. It would be easy to connect suite with my modules/use cases.